# Assign property value automatically from other properties within an object

Tags: c#, .net, class, oop, dynamic

I have the following `Class`

```
public class BlogPost
{
    public int BlogPostId             { get; set; }
    public string BlogPostTitle       { get; set; }
    public string BlogPostDescription { get; set; }
    public int Upvotes    { get; set; }
    public int Downvotes  { get; set; }
    public int TotalVotes { get; set; }
}
```

How would you automatically assign `TotalVotes = Upvotes - Downvotes` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for a [calculated property](https://csharp.2000things.com/tag/calculated-property/). So it should be something like this:

```
public int TotalVotes
{ 
    get { return Upvotes - Downvotes; } 
}
```

Or if you are using C# 6+ you can use [expression body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members) like this:

```
public int TotalVotes => Upvotes - Downvotes;
```

Comment: Thank you Akbari, I had come across an example on microsoft docs using a "Lambda"-Like expression to achieve the same and wanted to know how to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

You Need just to write your Operation in the return Path like:

```
public int TotalVotes { get { return Upvotes - Downvotes;} }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers by others would work , but I would prefer something like this (C# 6.0)

```
public class BlogPost
{
    public int BlogPostId { get; set; }
    public string BlogPostTitle { get; set; }
    public string BlogPostDescription { get; set; }
    public int Upvotes { get; set; }
    public int Downvotes { get; set; }
    public int TotalVotes {get => GetTotalVotes(); }   

    // A method just in case if you need to do some extra calculations or validations
    private int GetTotalVotes()
    {

        //I am assuming the TotalVotes should not go below 0;
        //You can change it as you like

        int value = UpVotes - DownVotes;

        return value<0? 0 : value;

    }
}
```